# Entity framework seed method never invoked

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I put this code in `global.asax` file:

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new BcoInitializer());
ApplicationDbContext c = new ApplicationDbContext();
c.Database.Initialize(true);
var x = c.ProductCategories.ToList();
```

And this recreate my database.
But `Seed()` was never invoked and I can't find out why?

```
public class BcoInitializer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            base.Seed(context);

            var currencies = new List<Currency>
            {                
                new Currency{CurrencyId="USD", Symbol="$"}
            };
```

This is my context:

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {   
            Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationDbContext>());
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for your context class:

```
 public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {   
        Database.SetInitializer(new BcoInitializer());
    }
```

Comment: I know it was something simple :) Thanks